# PostGIS with VPN

Tags: qgis, postgis, connection

Is it possible to use the PostGIS database with a VPN tunnel? The database tells me there is no connection possible.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using VPN Tracker 365.

Comment: While a PostgreSQL instance may have the PostGIS extension installed and added to a database, it's still a PostgreSQL instance, and PostgreSQL's security model which manages access. [dba.se] is likely a better place to research this topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That error message is coming from PostGIS (well Postgresql) and is saying that it "sees" you but that there is no entry in the pg_hba.conf file for the IP address you are coming from. You need to log on to (or ask your sysadmin) to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file to add 172.20.10.2 to the list of acceptable hosts.

Another option (if your server supports SSH) is to use an SSH connection to the server with port forwarding set, then PostGIS thinks your local pgadmin (or whatever) is connecting from localhost and is therefore (more) trustworthy.

Comment: thank you! I will try this. sysadmin is me (without a clue :-P )